# Can we install AMD64 programs via Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: ubuntu

I was planning to download some programs from snapcraft.io and to invest in a Raspberry Pi 4 8GB, and install Ubuntu on there, so I can run it. I was wondering if this was possible by any chance? Wasn't sure when looking!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not use programs compiled for the AMD64 on the Pi.

There are versions of Ubuntu which run on the Pi.

None are based on AMD64 which is an Intel compatible architecture.

The Raspberry Pi is ARM architecture.

Answer (score 1):

snapcraft.io also offers ARM builds of many apps they host, so you should check whether specific apps you want to run have an ARM version.

AFAIK you can run x86 apps on the Pi using [box86](https://github.com/ptitSeb/box86) or a similar emulator. I don't know how `snap` works exactly, but if it doesn't interfere with the executable file loader, there's a chance it'll work under box68 on a Pi.

Note that box86 is for x86, not AMD64. For AMD64 there's no support that I know of.